# Restore data in Cassandra 3.9. from snapshot taken in Cassandra 2.1.15

Tags: cassandra, snapshot

Did someone know, how to restore data in Cassandra 3.9. from snapshot taken in Cassandra 2.1.15 (before I upgraded Cassandra)?

Just copying snapshot files into proper data directory and executing "nodetool refresh" didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra use sstables to save data into files. These sstables have a version.

Cassandra [2.1.15 supports sstable versions](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.15/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/Descriptor.java#L52-L66) : 
ja (2.0.0), 
jb (2.0.1), 
ka (2.1.0):

Cassandra  [3.9 supports sstable versions](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.9/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L116-L127) :
jb (2.0.1),
ka (2.1.0),
la (2.2.0),
lb (2.2.7),
ma (3.0.0),
mb (3.0.7, 3.7),
mc (3.0.8, 3.9)

When [upgrading cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgrdCassandraDetails.html), you must use 'nodetool upgradesstable' to upgrade sstable format version to latest available before and after upgrading cassandra.

I think your sstables are in version ja (2.0.0) that is not supported by cassandra 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run nodetool upgradesstables.

Otherwise you can downgrade your 3.9 cluster to the version that supports your version sstbales version and upgrade it back afterwards.

And most secure option - create a side 2.1 cluster with 2.1 snapshots, and upgrade it until you get a needed version of sstables, take snapshot, restore to your 3.9 cluster.